# What is pyethereum?

Tags: ether, python, pyethereum, py-evm

I have seen a definition [here](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum) saying: "***This is the Python core library of the Ethereum project"***

So what is it's use? To develop dapps using python on the ethereum network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what is it's use?

pyethereum - the  core library, featuring the blockchain, the ethereum virtual machine, mining.

> To develop dapps using python on the ethereum network?

No.

Comment: So what exactly is it used to code?

Comment: mining, tx validation, VM task and so on.

Comment: so just to be sure I got it right... It is used to create programs that mine... but what is tx validation and VM task..

Comment: it's not _create a program to mine_ - pyethereum - __is a python ethereum implementation__, the same as `geth` but with some differ functionalities

Comment: What are the different functionalities? I am asking because I have seen pyethereum being used in implementing reality keys.

Comment: For example `geth` includes RPC server while `pyethereum` not.